# Selenium finding class inside div

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium

I am trying to access and click the 'X' button  via selenium in python to be able to be redirected to the next page and load some information from it. However, I am having a hard time finding the element, do not know whether it is because of being inside a class or something else. Can you guys help me out to actually click on the button. Code below is what I currently have.

Thank you in advance:

---

```
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
import time
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
url = 'https://shop.axs.co.uk/Lw%2fYCwAAAAA6dpvSAAAAAABB%2fv%2f%2f%2fwD%2f%2f%2f%2f%2fBXRoZW8yAP%2f%2f%2f%2f%2f%2f%2f%2f%2f%2f'
opts = Options()
browser = Firefox(options=opts)
browser.get(url)

#wait for all elements to load
time.sleep(5)
#working lines are commented out
#search_form = browser.find_element_by_class_name("modal-open")
browser.find_element_by_class_name('btn-close-svg pull-right').click()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this lines -

`opts = Options()
browser = Firefox(options=opts)`

use the xpath here-

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@class='btn-close-svg pull-right']").click()
```

Comment: with what you said and changed:
driver.get(url)
driver.find_element accordingly.

However I get an error: